# Javascript building objects from string

Tags: javascript

So in working with the google map api examples I am attempting to build a list of objects from a string. My java script is a little week here but the first chuck of code is the loop where I am creating the objects, I think.

The Locations parts is what it should look like in the end. If I use the locations with the objects the function works. But if i replace it with the loop objects it fails.

```
var myStr = "bob|44.654990|-88.129186|7:20 PM,karen|44.469493|-88.087746|8:19 PM";

var splitLocations = myStr.split(",");
var daLocs = [];
for(var z=0;z<splitLocations.length;z++){
    var breakdown = splitLocations[z].split("|");
    daLocs += '[' + breakdown[0] + ',' + breakdown[1] + ',' + breakdown[2] + ',' + z + '],';
}
var locations = [
    ['bob', 44.654990, -88.129186, 5],
    ['karen', 44.469493, -88.087746, 4]
]
```

Comment: Where do the `5` and the `4` come from in that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push an array into `daLocs`;

```
var myStr = "bob|44.654990|-88.129186|7:20 PM,karen|44.469493|-88.087746|8:19 PM";

var splitLocations = myStr.split(",");
var daLocs = [];
for(var z=0;z<splitLocations.length;z++){
    var breakdown = splitLocations[z].split("|");
    //daLocs += '[' + breakdown[0] + ',' + breakdown[1] + ',' + breakdown[2] + ',' + z + '],';
    daLocs.push([breakdown[0], breakdown[1], breakdown[2], z]);
}
```

For

```
daLocs[1][2] === "-88.087746"
```

(and `z === 0` to `splitLocations.length`)

Answer (score 0):

Without the magical `5` and `4` (since I can't fathom from whence they come), I'd suggest doing it this way:

```
var myStr = "bob|44.654990|-88.129186|7:20 PM,karen|44.469493|-88.087746|8:19 PM",
    parts = myStr.split(','),
    locations = [];

for (var i = 0, len = parts.length; i<len; i++){
    locations.push(parts[i].split('|'));
}

console.log(locations);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UuLdn/).

References:

- [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 0):

You don't use += to add to an array. You can change it to:

```
array.push(item);
```

Also, it seems like your expected result contains actual strings and numbers. In your loop, not only are you not using `parseInt`/`parseDouble`, but you're just appending the 4 values as a string, seperated by commas. I'm guessing instead you wanted individual arrays inside the `locations` array. So, take this example. The first "`[`" in this code is creating a new array:

```
daLocs.push([breakdown[0], parseDouble(breakdown[1]), ...TODO... ])
```